# Story about pilot fighting aliens

Tags: story-identification

This story starts with a semi-retired military pilot on patrol with a lizard-like alien friend. The enemies are also human and can control swarms of ships using a single pilot. He is forced to unite with one of the human enemies top pilots in order to face an alien invasion. The aliens fly large, globe shaped ships which they eventually manage to commandeer. It was a fun story and would really like to read it again.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Also just to clarify, this was a novel right? If not what was it? Can you remember roughly what year you read it? And if you remember anything else, plot details, settings, etc. don't hesitate to [edit] those details into your question!

Comment: It was a novel set in deep space, though they travel a fair amount too. I read it about 3 years ago but don't know if it was newly published im afraid. A large element is the relationship between our protagonist, a hero of the war, and a similarly ranked antagonist who he comes to respect and eventually admire over the course of the book. It has some large space battles in and a few alien species on both sides.